# Problem converting eps to pdf with pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, epstopdf

I am using pdflatex to convert eps figures to pdf as follow:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio{./Figures/R.eps}
   \label{fig_1}
\end{figure}
```

I am using these packages

```
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

When I compile, I get this error `! Package pdftex.def Error: File './Figures/R-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.`

I looked for a solution in the internet and in the tex stack exchange website. I found many but did not solve my problem. I have like 10 eps figures, 7 are working fine and 3 are not (I just added these 3 figures today).

When I remove the `[final]` from the graphicx package, I do not get the error but I cannot see the figures in the output pdf file.

the document class that I am using is: `\documentclass[draft, 12pt, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: Do you really use `pdflatex`?

Comment: Yes I am using texmaker. I compile my `.tex` file using the Quick Build option which is set to the `PdflaTeX + View PDF`.